# StreamWriter : Date format is wrong in excel file after writing csv file

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I'm using `StreamWriter` to write `csv` file.

This is the result when I opened it in Notepad++

[image]

But when I opened it in excel, it became like this

[image]

Notice that the format became `03-08-18` instead of `03/08/2018`, I notice that the format for 3rd column in excel is set to `Date` while 4th column is set to `General`. Any idea why? How do I force excel to apply all format as General?

Comment: You wrote *text* not dates. CSV tries to parse it using *your machine's locale*. If that text can't be parsed, it will be left as text. Only the US uses the MM/DD/YYYY format, which means a machine outside the US will always tread the last line as text. BTW the third column is full of August 3 2018 entries

Comment: If you want to use *Excel*, why don't you create *Excel* files, eg with a library like EPPlus? It's as simple as `sheet.LoadFromCollection(myList)`. If you want an unambiguous format, use `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: `How do I force excel to apply all format as General?` Write a xlsx file, not CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the text import wizard as described here:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-import-wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857

Here you can define the column separator and the way the date columns are interpreted.

For repeated use you can record your steps as VBA macro.

Answer (score -2):

You can solve in c#:

```
DateTime MyDate = DateTime.Now;
        MyDate.ToShortDateString().Replace("/", "-");
```

Or:

```
DateTime MyDate = DateTime.Now;
            MyDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```